# Guidelines for events since non-nullable references

Tags: c#

When working with C# 8 and the new non-nullable references, I realized that events are treated like fields. This means that they will cause a warning 90% of the time since they won't be initialized until someone subscribes to it.

Consider the following event:

```cs
public event EventHandler IdleTimeoutReached;
```

You get the following warning on the line of the constructor declaration.

> CS8618 C# Non-nullable event is uninitialized. Consider declaring the event as nullable.

If you make it nullable, the warning disappears of course. However, this looks very weird to me.

```cs
public event EventHandler? IdleTimeoutReached;
```

An alternative would be assigning it a no-op, but this seems even worse.

```cs
public event EventHandler IdleTimeoutReached = new EventHandler((o, e) => { });
```

What's the correct way to handle this situation and get rid of the warning without just disabling it? Are there any official guidelines for this?

Comment: Look at [nullable contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-contexts) at MSDN

Comment: Why is `EventHandler?` weird given that `EventHandler` is a delegate (reference type) that may acutally be uninitialized?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I did, I know I can just disable the warning but I thought maybe there's a more correct way.

Comment: @mm8 It just _looks weird_ to me which is not a good reason I know but I thought maybe there was a guideline or convention for this. The though of an event being null seems weird. If we only look at the term _event_ and forget about it just being a delegate with easy access (like someone who isn't very familiar with c# events might do), it sounds weird to say it might be null.

Comment: My analogy was like this: "If I don't come to your party, it won't be held right?" "No, of course it will still be held." Likewise my event still _exists_ even if noone cares for it. This is of course not right because of the nature of c# events but from a very objective point of view, this seems like a considerable thought. I guess you just have to accept what events actually are and then it makes sense.

Comment: You must always take into account the possibility of the event being `null`, hence patterns like `IdleTimeoutReached?.Invoke()`. It would make no sense for the compiler to lie to you and say "no, it's fine" only to then have invoking the event actually fail because it's `null`. The fact that *callers* don't have to deal with this (because the `+=` syntax takes care of it, and they're not allowed to get the value raw) is what's causing the confusion, but even to them the value really is `null`, and the delegate combination operator just transparently deals with that for them.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Exactly. Since the callers don't have to deal with it I thought maybe the 'host' (or whatever you call it) also doesn't. It would've made a lot of sense to me but then again `EventHandler?` aso makes sense. I guess that from c# 8 upwards we're just never going to see a non-nullable event ever again. Should I self answer my question or how do I handle this now seeing as it's bascially been resolved just in the comments?

Comment: @Joelius It might be beneficial to others if you self answer the question, because Stackoverflow is hiding the last two comments - I only read them because there are no other answers anywhere else.

Comment: I see this and won't argue with the comments and answer but I personally agree more with your ```new EventHandler((o, e) => { });``` answer.  Null is a type that is generically used and the whole point of the Nonnullable Reference Types is to hopefully remove that null option and prevent NullReferenceExceptions.  I know not many will agree but personally I feel that making anything Null, when you're intent is to avoid null, is just backwards hacking. I believe we should aim to justify the events.  If no one is assigning to it then of course let it run an empty event, IMO that is.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII, there is a slightly more concise way to initialize event handler fields, described as "[An alternate approach](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/01/)" by John Skeet back in 2015. In short, you can `public event EventHandler SomeEvent = delegate {}`. This initializer syntax works for any event type.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You should make the event nullable, because it is indeed nullable. It may look a bit strange but that's the correct way of expressing your intent.

It has always been necessary to check whether an event is null before raising it within the class. In this case nullable reference checking will warn you if you try to invoke it without checking for null.

```cs
    public class Publisher
    {
        public event EventHandler? IdleTimeoutReached;

        protected virtual void RaiseIdleTimeoutEvent()
        {
            // `IdleTimeoutReached` will be null if no subscribers; compiler gives warning about possible null reference
            IdleTimeoutReached.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

            // No compiler warning
            IdleTimeoutReached?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

The nullable annotation really only adds value for the class invoking the event. It won't affect callers at all because the `+=` / `-=` syntax takes care of correctly assigning/removing those delegates.

So you should use:

```
public event EventHandler? IdleTimeoutReached;
```

For events with `EventArgs`, use:

```
public event EventHandler<IdleTimeoutEventArgs>? IdleTimeoutReached;
```

Comment: Tobias J: I have used [AllowNull] attribute for this error.  Is there anything wrong with that approach?

Comment: It's weird to have to add `?` to an event handler declaration. That would mean for over 25 years we've had these possible `null` reference exceptions lurking around uninitialized event handlers. Except...there is no concern for `null` event handlers, and no risk of a **NullReferenceException** because the `+=` and `-=` take care of everything. Which means that the `null` code flow analysis doesn't understand that `null` isn't a problem in this case. This probably will get fixed with the **API Annotations** that they're writing for .NET Core first, and promise to add to .NET Framework in time.

Comment: @IanBoyd that's not true; you have _always_ had to check events for null before raising them. The nullable `event` isn't for the subscribers (where `+=` and `-=` does indeed take care of it); it's for the class you're invoking it from. See the `OnRaiseCustomEvent` method in [Microsoft's code example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-publish-events-that-conform-to-net-framework-guidelines); you must check `if (raiseEvent != null)` before invoking it. So yes, this possible `NullReferenceException` has been lurking the entire time.

Comment: I do agree that it's "ugly" in the case of events and I'm sure if they were designing the language from scratch today with nullable reference types in mind they'd find a more elegant solution. But this is the unfortunate spot we're in with the feature being added after the fact.

Comment: Except that the warning isn't coming from where we *"call"* the event (which is already wrapped in a check for `null`). This error is happening on the class itself, just as the top of the class. It **seems** like it wants us to *construct* an **EventHandler<T>** object during object creation - but that's not needed, nor what any documentation says. The error is **"Non-nullable event '%s' is uninitialized."** Lets say i **wanted** to initialize it - there is no such thing. You can't initialize it even if you wanted to. So the warning is just weird.

Comment: @IanBoyd that's the same thing it does for all nullable reference types. When you see a warning "non-nullable x is uninitialized" there's the implied, "or make it nullable to leave it uninitialized". Agree their guidance and specific messaging here is lacking and that events should not be initialized with a default value. Same thing with EF Core DbSet properties on a DbContext... these are cases where things don't fit neatly into the strict checking. Your only options are to leave it non-nullable and suppress the warning, turn off nullable checks in the class, or make it nullable.

Comment: I like the definitive *"It doesn't make much sense in this case, and so just add `?` to shut up the compiler."*

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of non-nullable reference types in C# is to obviate the need for writing code that deals with nulls. Null checks make code more verbose and harder to read. By removing the need for always having to do null checking, code is made more concise and readable.

In that spirit, I would recommend that you require a reference to an event handler in the constructor for the type in which your event appears. This will make the compiler happy, and it means that every time your type containing an event is instantiated, there will be an event handler in place to handle your event. **This ensures that your type is always used in the way that it is intended to be used.**

Now, someone might say that it is better to make the event nullable so that it is optional. My view, however, is that if a type defines an event, it does so for an important reason, and if the user of that type wishes to ignore that important reason and not use the event, then that user can define an empty event handler so that it is made clear in the code that the event is intentionally being ignored.

In the end you get better communication between classes, and you also eliminate the need for null checks, so the benefits are twofold.

The code would look something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var myType1 = new MyType(IdleTimeout);
        
        // Or if you don't want a superfluous handler in your code,
        // you can use a Lambda.
        var myType2 = new MyType((sender, e) => {});
    }

    static void IdleTimeout(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Event ignored.
    }
}

class MyType
{
    public MyType(EventHandler idleTimeoutReached)
    {
        IdleTimeoutReached += idleTimeoutReached;
    }

    public event EventHandler IdleTimeoutReached;

    public void TimeoutReached()
    {
        // Any required logic goes here.

        IdleTimeoutReached?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: By that logic it would mean that in the case of for example controls with lots of events that currently can optionally be subscribed to, one would need to subscribe to every possible event the control exposes. I agree it's good practice in some cases, but it won't be feasible in others.

Comment: @Daap Good point. An event-laden UI control that requires acknowledgement of all events would be very annoying indeed. In any case, this is another approach that's useful for when events are mission critical.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same confusion, and here is my answer after checked the source code of the .NET framework as @Tobias J said.

It seems that we need to append a `?` to the type of the `event` handler as a `nullable reference type`. For example, the following code snippet of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface from the .NET 6.0 framework.

```cs
#region Assembly System.ObjectModel, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
// C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.19\ref\net6.0\System.ObjectModel.dll
#endregion

#nullable enable


namespace System.ComponentModel
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Notifies clients that a property value has changed.
    public interface INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Occurs when a property value changes.
        event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```