# "Non-nullable event must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor"

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates, non-nullable

Im getting the warning **"Non-nullable event 'SomeEvent' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the event as nullable."**

Here's a very simplified version of my code which replicates the exact same problem. What am I missing here? Does this have anything to do with .Net 6?

```
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    public delegate void SomeDelegate(object sender, EventArgs args);

    public class NewClass
    {
        public NewClass(string name)
        {
            this.name = name;

        }

        public string name { get; set; }

        public event SomeDelegate SomeEvent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not near my development machine but I usually declare my events like this: `public event SomeDelegate SomeEvent = delegate { };` to prevent it from being null

Comment: `public event SomeDelegate? SomeEvent;` should fix that warning, make it `nullable`.

Comment: As @zaggler said, but when you invoke the event don't forget to do use it like this `SomeEvent?.Invoke(...);`

Comment: all 3 fixed the problem, thanks. obviously i should expand my knowledge on delegates and events, but it weirded me out that it doesn't happen on .net 5, but only on .net 6.

Comment: It's only happening because you have nullable reference types enabled for the project.

Comment: @DavidG is correct, I think it's enabled by default as well.

Comment: just checked the .csproj file and yeah, that's the issue.

Answer (score 13):

I know I'm late to the party, but Google sent me here, and the only responses were unsatisfactory. [I came upon another answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58376972/guidelines-for-events-since-non-nullable-references/62536248#62536248) that felt a lot better, and you can get a good explanation there.

tl;dr just make the event nullable, because that's what it actually is:

```
public event SomeDelegate? SomeEvent;
```

Comment: Language syntax weirdness (this is what had me messed up): The question mark goes after the "type" declaration. Normally, the "type" is a single word near the beginning of the declaration (e.g., the word `string` in `public string? myString;`. But events are special. The "type" is two words: the keyword `event` followed by the delegate name. So, the question mark goes after the delegate name.

Answer (score -1):

Initialize the property to the default.

```
public string name { get; set; } = default!;
```